# Why are progressCallbacks useful?

Tags: jquery

A `Deferred` object has the callback pools `doneCallbacks`, `failCallbacks` and `progressCallbacks`.

Both `doneCallbacks` and `failCallbacks` (together with the methods `done`, `fail`, `always`, `reject`, `resolve`, etc.) are useful.

What is a typical use case for `progressCallbacks`?

Comment: Show a progessbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9398, it's offers progressive notifications. This is handy when dealing with long asynchronous tasks such as xhr2 uploads. So yes, as Guillaume86 suggests, it could be used in conjunction with a progress indicator such as a progressbar.